Error: "Id = 152, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}""
I tried the below code to get the content but each time I am receiving this error
var content = await graphClient.Users[""].MailFolders["inbox"].Messages[message.Id].Content.GetAsync();


Error: "Id = 152, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}""

As well please provide me list for permission to be enable at Application, User level etc. permission like Mail.ReadWrite, User.Read, etc. For reading email, content, attachments and move email to specific folder of the shared emailbox

I'm afraid you are trying to call this API, the sample showed us with await graphClient.Me.Messages["{message-id}"].Content.GetAsync();, so that could you pls try var content = await graphClient.Users["userId"].Messages[message.Id].Content.GetAsync(); which removing the folder? By the way, I also found var res = await graphServiceClient.Me.Messages["{message-id}"].Content.GetAsync(); var data = new StreamReader(res).ReadToEnd(); which shows us how to read content.

from this question:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1344310/c-graph-api-)-5-0-15-content-getasync()-not-workin

Because your using that method asynchronously WaitingForActivation just means its yielded https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await back the caller. If you try to access the result of the Task that would would block until the task had completed (which would execute the method are return the actual result in that property) Await vs Task.Result in an Async Method
The other thing you can do if your just testing/playing with this is execute it synchronously eg
 var content = graphClient.Users[""].MailFolders["inbox"].Messages[""].Content.GetAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

